# php curl to read data from webpage

Tags: php, curl

I am given a project on fetching data from [this url](http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/MainSearchProductCategory.html?q=4960999299662).

For this, Simple HTML DOM process has already failed, so I am working on:

```
function curl_download($Url){
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/MainSearchProductCategory.html?q=0018208925063");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

print curl_download('www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/MainSearchProductCategory.html?q=0018208925063');
```

This code returns a blank page. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Shouldn't you be putting an http:// before the www. in the address?

Comment: @BaileyHerbert i have putt http:// still its showing a blank page

Comment: Your answer is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648741/blank-reponse-on-a-curl-request-php/31648993#31648993

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the Useragent you used is too short to look like a real browser.

Try to use this one bellow:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.38");`